# Present Popover from Modal View Controller

Tags: ipad, modal-dialog, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to present a Popover from a button in a UIModalPresentationPageSheet. It crashes the app and returns the following message to the console:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

My code works fine in a standard view controller. As the message suggests, there is something about the modal that prevents it displaying. I've done a fair amount of searching on this topic, but am not finding a solution. I have to believe it is possible, as I've seen something very similar in apps like 1Password.

Pointers and/or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be working for me, try this :

```
[_pPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 900) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which SDK did you use, but I don't get any exception with 5.1. I am showing a popover from a text field and the following code works:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[_popController presentPopoverFromRect:textField.frame
                                inView:textField.superview
              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                              animated:YES];
return NO;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the problem is that you're passing a view controller instead of a view for the inView parameter. It's trying to fetch the .window for a UIViewController, and UIViewControllers don't have one, UIViews do.